# What's the best way to paint in Unity?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, mobile

I'm making a little game, you're given a canvas and have to completely fill it up by painting everything. The problem is that I don't know how to let the user draw on an object in the UI.

I researched 2DTextures and their setPixel() method, but that seems limiting, because making an 800x600 2DTexture would mean you'd have to paint 480000 pixels, and that's too much. If I make the 2DTexture smaller, 150x100 for example, it would be to small. I'd basically need to make the pixels "bigger", each one being a 4x4 of the real pixels.

Another thing I thought of is making a grid in the UI (150x100) and make the single cells change color then touched. Is this viable? How would I go about doing it?

Last thing, I need to check when the canvas is finished, so I need a way to check the color of every pixel (or cell,in case of the grid), would iterating every pixel with getPixel() be fast enough?

Comment: Shader or go with native and use API's like OpenCV as plugin to do this. `SetPixel` should not be used for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have any examples or tutorials on how to use a shader or OpenCV to accomplish this?

Comment: If you search for "Unity shader draw" an Open CV draw", you will find many things.  If you decide to use OpenCV, it has to be C++ instead of python to make it possible to run on many platform. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d96/tutorial_basic_geometric_drawing.html) is a basic one for OpenCV.